# How to create a no-reply email with own domain email + nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, email, godaddy-api

I have a website that requires people to confirm their emails upon registration. My backend server is a node server. I am using nodemailer to deliver these confirmation emails.

For testing, I am currently using a gmail account to send these emails. And this is working perfectly.

Now however, I would like to upgrade and use my own domain email. And I would like to send out these emails under an email address like "no-reply@mydomain.com"

One of the requirements for my site is that it can handle sending up to **2000 confirmation emails in a day**.

I have looked at email hosting like godaddy and it says that one email account with them allows only 250 emails a day, which is way less than 2000.

So, **how can I achieve 2000 emails a day in the cheapest way possible?** Any recommendations will be helpful.

Thank you in advance for helping me with my question.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [GSuite](https://gsuite.google.ca/intl/en_ca/solutions/new-business/) by Google.
Once registered simply create a no-reply email (If I recall correctly, nodemailer needs the email to exist on the smtp server to work) and link it up. Good luck

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I looked at GSuite - pretty promising. Just one followup question: do I need OAuth for my Nodemailer to interact with GSuite?

Comment: Hey, you shouldnt need to. [Check this thread out](https://support.google.com/a/thread/7960511?hl=en). Also remember to enable "unsecure apps" for your account too, sometimes that makes SMTP not work. Good luck!